# How does Webpacker determines the path for imported media in Rails 6 (.svg etc)?

Tags: svg, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm using Streamline icons. I import a svg icon this way:

```
import Icon from '@streamlinehq/streamlinehq/img/streamline-light/users/geomertic-close-up-multiple-users/multiple-neutral-2.svg'
```

The svg icon ends up being compiled at: `/packs/media/geomertic-close-up-multiple-users/multiple-neutral-2-6a0b9211.svg`

I understand that `/packs/media` is the default for media elements (images, fonts, svgs etc), but what about the rest? How did Webpacker decide not to include the previous folders like `streamline-light/users`?

Where, or at what level, is that configured?

I'm asking because there are different font families, with icons having similar names in each of them. So if the family name is not included in the path for the compiled asset, then it causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom loader for these icons. I think the issue I was seeing was expected looking at the way rails configures webpack.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, or reply with a better answer, and I'll accept it :)

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const { join } = require('path');

const streamlinehqIconRegexp = /.*@streamlinehq.*\.(svg)$/i;

environment.loaders.get('file').exclude = streamlinehqIconRegexp;

module.exports = {
  test: streamlinehqIconRegexp,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        name: (fullPath) => {
          let iconFamily = fullPath.match(/img\/streamline-([^\/]+)/)[1]

          if (iconFamily == "light")
            iconFamily = "";

          return join(
            "media/icons",
            iconFamily,
            "[name]-[hash:8].[ext]"
          );
        }
      },
    }
  ]
}
```